# c# Remove nodes from xml file irrespective of hierarchy

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Please see my demo. I want to remove all the duplicate placemark nodes irrespective of the hierarchy. Is this possible with Linq? What would be the best way to remove all duplicate nodes and save as new xml file.

Also please note that for demo I have created a string otherwise I would be loading the xml file from the computer path.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/vAA6Xu

**Update**

```
    var raw = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><kml xmlns= 'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
      <Document>
          <Folder>
  <Placemark>
    <name>1</name>
    <description>abc</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>102.595626,14.996729</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>2</name>
    <description>abc</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>102.595626,14.996729</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>2</name>
    <description>abc</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>102.595626,14.996729</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>4</name>
    <description>abc</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>102.595626,14.996729</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>

   <Folder>
          <Placemark>
            <name>3</name>
            <description>abc</description>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>102.595626,14.996729</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>4</name>
            <description>abc</description>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>102.595626,14.996729</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>4</name>
            <description>abc</description>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>102.595626,14.996729</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
</Folder>
</Folder> 
<Placemark>
  <name>4</name>
  <description>abc</description>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>102.595626,14.996729</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>

<Placemark>
  <name>4</name>
  <description>abc</description>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>102.595626,14.996729</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
      </Document>
    </kml>";
```

The code

```
    var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(raw);
    XNamespace ns = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";
    xdoc.Root.Elements(ns+"Document").Elements(ns+"Placemark").GroupBy(i => (string)i).SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1)).Remove();
```

I want to find all Placemark nodes and remove the duplicate ones irrespective of hierarchy

Comment: It depends on which placemark you want to keep when removing the duplicate

Comment: I want to remove all which are duplicate except the first one i.e. from anywhere

Comment: Ok so if going through them whichever you find first remains and the rest(duplicates only must be removed right?)

Comment: @ csharpwinphonexaml - yes found anywhere in the file remove the duplicate node

Comment: I've done a lot of work with these map xml files.  What are you considering duplicate.  The file is hierarchical and you will have duplicates on different levels of the hierarchy.

Comment: How do you decide on duplicates?

Comment: As said i want to find all Placemark nodes and remove the duplicate ones. Like for example in demo all <Placemark><name>4</name> nodes will be removed except the first one. And Also <Placemark><name>2</name> will also be removed except the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding the concatenation of Placemark Node's values to a dictionary.
If you find the node's values in the dictionary it's a duplicate and you can call `.Remove()` on it.
One way to do it:

```
var raw = "yourxmlhere";
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(raw);
XNamespace ns = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";

Dictionary<string,bool> dictionary = new Dictionary<string,bool>();
var descendants = xdoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "Placemark").ToList();

foreach(var node in descendants){
    string key = string.Join("", node.Elements().Select(el => el.Value));
    if(dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        node.Remove();
    else
        dictionary.Add(key, true);
}
//at this point your xdoc only contains unique Placemark nodes
```